# How to get rid of response messages initiating Google Chrome using ChromeDriver in Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have problem with this that I want to have a clean terminal/output but when I use selenium in python and when I call :
`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

I get this message between my output :

```
[14096:8964:1002/201524.623:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(228)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[14096:8964:1002/201524.623:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(231)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended. 
[14096:8964:1002/201524.632:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(234)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[14096:5428:1002/201524.633:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [20:15:24.633] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1073 Getting Default Adapter failed.
[14096:8964:1002/201524.660:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(238)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
```

My code doesn't have any errors but I get this temp output
How can I remove this output? any code I need to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These error messages...

```
[5124:4344:1128/184821.088:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(226)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[5124:4344:1128/184821.145:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(229)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
```

...are the reasult of some *Parametrized tests are flaky due to a timeout in recording expensive metrics on startup*.

---

As per the discussion [Parametrized tests are flaky due to a timeout in recording expensive metrics on startup](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1216328) *`isherman@chromium.org`* mentions either of the calls in [chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/metrics/chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc;l=199;drc=a4f34441d6ba2bfec6a21e2ff88afaf2d18eb9db) are flaky:

- [*bluetooth_utility::ReportBluetoothAvailability()*](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/metrics/chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc;l=227;drc=a4f34441d6ba2bfec6a21e2ff88afaf2d18eb9db)
- [*shell_integration::GetDefaultBrowser()*](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/metrics/chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc;l=231;drc=a4f34441d6ba2bfec6a21e2ff88afaf2d18eb9db)

Seems *`asvitkine@chromium.org`* have submitted a [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/df6c9e0a0802cf1e5620c5c5c711dd5231da7cc5) mentioning:

> Don't log histogram DefaultBrowser.State on Linux. The code to query
> the default browser state sometimes hangs Chrome start up on browser
> tests bots, causing flakiness. Disable the relevant code on Linux
> until a solution can be found. Also, revise some instrumentation
> messages to be more concise and more clear about when the bug in
> question might happen. Once this lands, we should be able to see if
> any more tests are affected by this or whether the bug can be closed
> and diagnostic logs can be removed.

This fix should address the issue in the upcoming releases once the *flaky tests* are addressed.

---

### Temporary Solution

If you want to suppress the error logs you can add the  experimental option `'excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']` through an instance of `ChromeOptions()` as follows:

- *Python* solution:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  ```
- *Java* solution:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setExperimentalOptions("excludeSwitches", ['enable-logging']);
  ```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Selenium with Python then add these extra options into your Selenium code which will disable all the errors getting displayed on Console-

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use playwright:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install playwright
playwright install
```

```py
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto("http://playwright.dev")
        print(await page.title())
        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

This is the [Docs](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/next/intro) of playwright

Comment: oh ok thank you , it helped me so much